# Image button not clickable in HTML5/CSS3

Tags: html, image, css, button

I have an issue getting an image to be clickable on my site. All of my standard buttons with links work fine. Below I will paste my CSS and HTML5 code relevant to the button in question. I am leaving out the actual link for obvious reasons.

```css
.button3 {
  background-image: url("donate.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 500px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button3">
  <a href="link" class="button3"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: is it because the image isn't found and you don't have any content inside the anchor when it can't be found so there isn't anything to click?

Comment: @chennighan the image shows properly as desired and the mouse hovers properly, but on click nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead wrap your div button in the anchor tag, that way your anchor tag will stretch to be the width and height of its contents, allowing you to make your entire div clickable.

See example below:

```css
.button3 {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=f13ebeedfa9e");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  /*margin-left:500px;
  margin-right:5px;*/
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<a href="link">
  <div class="button3">
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: depending on his implementation, it could be better to use inputs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image

Comment: @nick parsons wrapping the anchor tags around the div class yielded the same result. The image hovers properly as if when it is clicked it will take me to a link, but upon clicking there is no response.

Comment: @Cale does the above snippet work for you? If it does but doesn't work in your code then there must be another issue with some other part of your site which is causing this

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. (replace your image with the s/o one). With your current styles, I added the `display: inline-block` to the **anchor**.

```
.button3 {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=f13ebeedfa9e");
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 500px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```
<a href="link" class="button3"></a>
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/irmoathlete/0dp21n48/)

Comment: ok, now I'm closer to my solution, except a bit more confused. The difference here seems to be the display attribute. if i copy-paste your code and substitute my link and my image url, my image no longer shows up. if i paste your code and have 2 .button3's on my css stylesheet, both of my images show up and one is working and clickable, the other is showing but not clickable. both .button3's on my stylesheet are identical, yet if i only have one on the stylesheet my image for my button will not show up...

Comment: There's no way for us to know what other styles are effecting it based on what we've seen from your snippet. We are just working with what you give us.